# Which 3D file formats can be made to allow XAML binding and code-behind animiation, etc. in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

Which 3D file formats can I use as a model in WPF that will allow me to access it's individual components (shapes) via WPF/XAML *Binding* and *Code-Behind*?

Same, simple project: 3D of world, make USA glow red, or something...

I'm not asking for product recommendations.

Comment: Yes. I understand that conversion(s) will be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you want to work with WPF 3D, you'll need to use xaml as your format.  WPF has it's own XAML formats which can be used to provide (named or unnamed) access to individual elements.

That being said, it's, in general, fairly limited in what it can do, since there isn't the ability to overwrite the rendering pass entirely.  For example, "glowing red" is probably going to have to be faked by having a separate red element tranformed and transparent, as there isn't really a direct way to add glow effects to objects in the WPF 3D pipeline. The [Helix3D samples](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) tend to show off some of the more elaborate WPF 3D rendering options (which are usually handled via workarounds).

Comment: Thanks for writing! But wouldn't there be a way to represent individual countries in XAML (as points, positions, etc.) so that each could be bound separately? I mean, if the 3d modeler has them as separate shapes, which formats are convertible to individual XAML objects? Failing in that (would be disappointing), I could use 2d images & place them, but wouldn't that be re-inventing the wheel, so to speak?

Comment: @PatTrainor You'd typically import from some other 3d format into the XAML toolchain.  Helix (linked above) has some great examples of importing from obj and other formats.

Comment: Well, the rub is that I can buy a pre-made 3D globe, with country definitions (I only need 1!) in any number of formats. But since I don;t know the workflow to get each shape in the model to be bindable/addressable, I don;t know which one(s) will work (with the fewest steps)... So the question is a 2-parter: which format for source, and the conversion necessary to make each shape 'addressable', if I can use that term...:)

Comment: @PatTrainor I'd use Helix, which has a few loaders.  You can see what the options are when you try it there...